What's the difference between the one-particle perturbation theory and many-body perturbation theory?
When I reading Hewson's book (The Kondo Problem to Heavy Fermions) about Kondo's explanation to resistance minimum, I encounter a sentence which saying
'The s-d Hamiltonian cannot be reduced to the single particle form $H_0=\sum\varepsilon c^\dagger c$ as it always can, at least in principle, for pure potential scattering. The modification required in the calculation of the T matrix in the many-body case can be stated quite simply; we have to replace the occupation numbers for electrons (or holes) in the intermediate $\boldsymbol{k}$ states by the Fermi factor $f(\varepsilon_{\boldsymbol{k}})$ ($(1-f(\varepsilon_{\boldsymbol{k}}))$ for holes)'.
I don't know why the Fermi factor reflects the many-body effect.
Explicitly, the s-d Hamiltonian reads
$$H_{sd}=J\sum_{k,k'}(S^+c^{\dagger}_{k\downarrow}c_{k'\uparrow}+S^-c^{\dagger}_{k\uparrow}c_{k'\downarrow}+S_{z}(c^{\dagger}_{k\uparrow}c_{k'\uparrow}-c^{\dagger}_{k\downarrow}c_{k'\downarrow})),$$
T matrix reads
$$T=H_{sd}+H_{sd}G_{0}^+H_{sd}+\cdots.$$
For second-order Born approximation, we have
$$\langle k'\sigma'|T|k\sigma\rangle=\langle k'\sigma'|H_{sd}G_{0}^+H_{sd}|k\sigma\rangle.$$
For the process $\langle k'\uparrow|T|k\uparrow\rangle$, one of the contributions reads
$$J^2\sum_{k_1k_1'k_2k_2'}\langle k'\uparrow|S^-c_{k_1\uparrow}^\dagger c_{k_1'\downarrow}G_{0}^+S^+c_{k_2\downarrow}^\dagger c_{k_2'\uparrow}|k\uparrow\rangle$$
$$=J^2\sum_{k_2}S^-S^+(1-f(\varepsilon_{k_2}))G_{0}^+.$$
I don't know why the intermediate states must be the hole states. Why not the other low-lying excited states, i.e., particle states?
Repeatedly, I don't know why the Fermi factor reflects the many-body effect.
